# Why does authenticate directive lead to "Error: type mismatch"?

Tags: spray

I'm getting this error in my spray project.

```
Error:(41, 28) type mismatch;
 found   : spray.routing.authentication.ContextAuthenticator[co.s4n.authentication.entities.Usuario]
    (which expands to)  spray.routing.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Either[spray.routing.Rejection,co.s4n.authentication.entities.Usuario]]
 required: spray.routing.directives.AuthMagnet[?]
              authenticate(validateToken) {
                           ^
```

This is my TokenValidator trait

```
trait TokenValidator {

  def validateToken: ContextAuthenticator[Usuario] = {
    ctx =>
      val header = ctx.request.headers.find(_.name == "Access_Token")
      if (header isDefined) {
        doAuth(header.get)
      }
      else {
        Future(Left(AuthenticationFailedRejection(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsMissing, List())))
      }
  }

  def doAuth(header: HttpHeader): Future[Authentication[Usuario]] = {
    Dao.validateToken(header.value).map {
      case Some(usuario) => Right(usuario)
      case None => Left(AuthenticationFailedRejection(AuthenticationFailedRejection.CredentialsRejected, List()))
    }
  }


}
```

and this is the line where I¡m getting that error

```
//@DELETE
  //localhost:9090/authenticacion/users/{{userEmail}}
  val `users/{{email}}` =
    pathPrefix(`path-prefix`) {
      pathPrefix(`users-path-prefix` / Segment) {
        emailRef => {
            delete {
              authenticate(validateToken) { **HERE!!!!**
                usuario =>
                  .....
              }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Thak you all in advance!

Answer (score 11):

The only thing I was missing was to have `ExecutionContext` in scope and `import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` worked fine.

It's to let `Future`s work as they declare an implicit `ExecutionContext` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, saved me some time )

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time since the actual question came, but the way to go with this for Spray is to determine the execution context with the tools that Spray provides:

```
implicit def executionContext = actorRefFactory.dispatcher
```